# Referencing operator ::

Tags: operators, ocaml

I'm used to using `( + )` to reference the pervasive integer addition operator, but this doesn't work for `( :: )`:

> ```
>         OCaml version 4.01.0
>
> # (+);;
> - : int -> int -> int = <fun>
> # ( :: );;
> Error: Syntax error: operator expected.
> # ( := );;
> - : 'a ref -> 'a -> unit = <fun>
> ```

---

[The expression grammar](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) says

> ```
> expr  ::= ...
>         | expr  ::  expr
>         ...
>         ∣ [ expr  { ; expr }  [;] ]  
>         ...
>         | expr  infix-op  expr
>         ...
> ```

and [lexical conventions](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#infix-symbol) says

> ```
> infix-symbol  ::=  (= ∣  < ∣  > ∣  @ ∣  ^ ∣  | ∣  & ∣  + ∣  - ∣  * ∣  / ∣  $ ∣  %) { operator-char }
> ```

which seems to exclude both `::` and `:=` as infix operators, even though `( := )` works just fine.

---

What is `::`'s status as an operator?

Is there a convenient handle for the list prepend operator or is `(fun el ls -> el::ls)` the best one can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::` is a base construction that can't be implemented with other constructions. `:=` is an operator that can be implemented as `let (:=) r v = r.contents <- v`. But I agree that this contradicts the lexical conventions described in the manual.

For your problem of using `(::)`, the best you can do is to give it a short name if you want to use it multiple times. `let cons h t = h :: t`

Comment: It does not contradict the lexical grammar.

Answer (score 2):

The cons operator `::` is a constructor, and it can't be applied as an infix operator.

[Have a look at the pervasive module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) for a list of all the ones you can use like that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about `::` being a constructor.  That makes sense.  I did look at `module Pervasives` but was confused because it's maddeningly incomplete; for example, it doesn't define `type 'a list` :)

Answer (score 2):

> which seems to exclude both :: and := as infix operators, even though
>   ( := ) works just fine.

You made a jump there. You cite

```
expr  ::= ...
        | expr  infix-op  expr
```

But then you did not look at `infix-op`, which is defined as

```
infix-op    ::= infix-symbol  
         ∣   * ∣  + ∣  - ∣  -. ∣  = ∣  != ∣  < ∣  > ∣  or ∣  || ∣  & ∣  && ∣  :=  
         ∣   mod ∣  land ∣  lor ∣  lxor ∣  lsl ∣  lsr ∣  asr
```

So there, `:=` is a infix operator, along with other ones like `mod`, etc. `infix-symbol` is only for *custom* infix operators.

Comment: Yep, I must have glossed over the difference between "op" and "symbol".  Thanks for pointing that out.